# What is the Precision of SymPy's 'expand' Function?

Tags: python, precision, sympy

I am trying to expand a function of the form `(X + Y + Z) ^ N` where N is sufficiently large so that the expanded product will contain terms with coefficients much greater than 2 ^ 64; for the sake of this discussion let's just say that N is greater than 200. This is an issue because I am hoping to do an analysis of the expanded form of this function, and this analysis requires exact precision for all of the terms and their coefficients.

To expand the function I am using the Python module `SymPy`, which has seemed very promising thus far and been able to expand functions where N is > 150 in a relatively short amount of time. My concern though is that after looking through some of the expanded functions, I am seeing coefficients with more trailing zeroes than I might expect. I know that I can run everything through [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) for my analysis after the function has been expanded, but as of now, I am unsure as to whether or not some of the larger coefficients are even exactly correct in the first place.

Under the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#polynomial-rational-function-simplification) for SymPy's `expand` function, there is no clarification of how precise the coefficients of the expansion are when working with very large numbers. I know for a fact that `SymPy` uses the `mpmath` module for some of its functions, so I know that it is capable of arbitrary precision, I just don't know if arbitrary precision explicitly applies to this case.

I know that I could also confirm if the `expand` function is arbitrarily precise or not by summing all of the coefficients of a given function and checking whether or not that sum is equal to N, but I'd rather not spend a few hours coding all the necessary pieces to make that assessment, only to find out that `expand` is imprecise.

If anyone has any suggestions for easier ways to confirm the precision of `expand`, then I would appreciate that if direct confirmation of its precision cannot be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [PR 18960](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18960) has not yet been merged, you can affirm there that the coefficients are correct:

```
>>> multinomial(15,16,14)
50151543548788717200
>>> ((x+y+z)**(15+16+14)).expand().coeff(x**15*y**16*z**14)
50151543548788717200
>>> _ > 2**64
True
```

Since Python supports unlimited integers and the coefficients are integers, I don't know any reason that they would not be accurate.

Comment: I just want to add that it's important that X, Y, Z and N are all exact. No floats should be used in the calculation if you want the coefficients to be exact.

Comment: I suppose I just wasn't sure if there was at any point some float conversion being undergone within the expansion process. I still do find myself using a lot of C/Java principles as well, and it's still not very intuitive to me that the "bignum" Python integer is now the standard. I'll take your word for it then that there are no float conversions happening and proceed with working with `SymPy`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that if you aren't working with Floats and don't have a Float in the output the calculation from SymPy should be exact since everything is being dealt with symbolically. Consider the circumference for an `Ellipse((0,0),3,2).circumference -> 12*elliptic_e(5/9)` is exact (though not a Float); to get an approximation this can be evaluated (e.g. `Ellipse((0,0),3,2).circumference.n(3) -> 15.9`)